# Use AWS services without an AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I was wondering if I could use AWS organisation and AWS SSO to provide access to AWS services to someone without an AWS account.

Is it possible using the above mentioned services or some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS SSO could be used which would utilise the credentials of whatever Identity Provider you can connect to SSO i.e. OKTA/Active Directory etc.

With that setup an AWS account would not be provided as their access would be assumed through a permission set/role you create, and they can consume AWS services

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/manage-your-identity-source.html